# Japanese Verbs: Causative form

Tags: business-japanese

Can someone tell me why there is て in between 休ませ and ください?

The sentence is: *今日は仕事を休ませてください。*

I know I have conjugated the verb 休む in the causative form but didn't get why the て is used after it. Is it the **te** form? Or some other grammatical element? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is just the causative form + ～てください.

休む　→　休ませる　→　休ませて　→　休ませてください

> 今日は仕事を休ませてください　→　Please allow me to stay home (and rest) from work today.

Comment: Thank you, how did you get 休ませて? Did you use the te to make it continuous? Or is te a part of てください?

Comment: 休ませて is just the 〜て form of 休ませる.  Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Ah yes, I mistyped there. Sorry about that, I wanted to know whether it is the te form or not. So it is.

Answer (score 2):

Polite requests are made in the form of ～てください. 手紙を書いて下さい。りんごを食べて下さい。 Take 休む, make it 休ませる, and then just follow the rules for polite requests and make it 休ませてください.

Comment: So, you just added てください right? After making it causative, nothing much right? Or is 休ませて different and ください is different.